# Limit to number of sensors attached to Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

Is there any limitation on how many sensors can be attached to one Arduino board? I am making elderly smart ban and I want to use GPS, GSM, gyroscope, pulse sensor, temperature sensor and I2C OLED. Right now I have only gyroscope, pulse sensor and GPS connected to Arduino Uno but I would like to add more stuff and also I am considering using Arduino Nano or only ATmega328P chip for finished product. My main concern is power.

Comment: Power is a concern, but the number of available pins is the more-limiting factor.  Even so, these units (I use Nano a lot) can easily handle several sensors simultaneously.  Mine output to Raspberry Pi via Serial cable so it can collect data for later processing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no answer that can be given to you that is "correct". However, there are things for you to consider in your design process:

1. Can you fit all the code in flash, and the required variables in RAM?
2. Does the chip have all the IO you need, and can you use the required internal / interfacing peripherals in the right combinations to satisfy your requirements
3. Do the devices fit within your power budget (battery capacity, required run-time, power regulation efficiency).

The Arduino is just a component. It belongs in a circuit, and that circuit is what determines everything else. The ATMega328P has certain power requirements, as do all the other components in your circuit. It is up to you to design the right power system to provide that power with the right efficiency and power saving options (switching off circuit segments when not needed to save power), etc.

For prototyping and experimenting the Arduino provides a rudimentary power supply which is wildly inefficient. Not recommended for any battery powered scenario or any high current usage.

Comment: Thank you for advice. For code it is ok, it fits. But i am worried for power. Idea for now is to add more batteries

Comment: Calculate how much current you need for your sensors first. No one can help you until you do that.